# Converting leading 0 String into Integer in java

Tags: java, string, casting, increment, number-formatting

I have following string in my java class

```
String str="0000000000008";
```

Now I want to increment that so that the next value should be 0000000000009

For that purpose, I tried to cast this String `str` into Integer

```
Integer i=Integer.parseFloat(str)+1;
```

and when I print the value of `i` it prints only 17(as it removes the leading 0's from string at the time of cast).

How can I increment the String value, so that the leading 0's will remain, and the series will continue?

Answer (score 7):

Practical solution - use `String.format`:

```
str = String.format("%013d", Long.parseLong(str)+1);
```

Comment: (didn't count the digits ;) it's only 13, not 17)

Comment: You could also do `str = String.format("%0" + str.length() + "d", Long.parseLong(str)+1);` to keep the number of digits in the original string.

Answer (score 5):

You are on the correct path. First parse to `Long`:

```
long cur = Long.parseLong("0000000000008");
```

increment and format back to `String` with leading `0`s:

```
new java.text.DecimalFormat("0000000000000").format(cur + 1);
```

or alternatively:

```
String.format("%013d", Long.valueOf(cur));
```

Comment: ..Thanks for the answer. But the String str is not a constant. It may be changed during run-time. So, is there any other solution for this?

Comment: @ArunKumar: so, what is wrong with: `Long.parseLong(knownAtRuntime)` where `knownAtRuntime` is a `String` variable?

Comment: @ Tomasz Nurkiewicz -- You are right. Your answer will work for a constant. But my concern is that this will not work for a String variable whose value may be changed during execution of program.